# How to force symfony2 to show nginx's default error pages

Tags: symfony, exception

I'm using Symfony2.4, and my question is:

```
- Symfony always tries exception and shows its error page
- But if my web faces 500 error, I want it to show default error page of nginx.
```

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The kernel is catching exception like 500, or 404...
By default, he call TwigBundle:Exception:show controller, that will choose the template to use.
Create this folder.

app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception

And add twig templates with the same name as TwigBundle's templates. They will override the default template.

Comment: I can customize the template for error pages, but what I want is we can show default error pages of nginx instead of symfony error pages

Comment: Why would you ever want this? If you're really desperate for the same look as the default error page just copy and paste the HTML.

Comment: I guess you need to change the exception handler, so you have to override the TwigBundle controller, and templates.
Its alot of work for nothing, good luck (making Listener, template...)

Comment: Haha, I've set up 500, 502 error pages for nginx, so I don't want symfony catches 500 error page (I can customize 500 error page of symfony, but this error page will be dulicated :( )
Thanks anyway!! :-)

Comment: As Peter said, I can copy and paste the HTML, but I want to find out a better way. :)